# Непонятка с типом переменной

Tags: c, float, c++

Добрый вечер!
Есть кусочек кода:

```
int a=2; int b=3;  
float srednar;  
srednar=(a+b)/2;  
cout<<<srednar<<endl;
```

Почему вывод результата 2, а не 2.5? srednar имеет же вещественный тип.

Comment: Потому что операции деления-умножения с int дают результат в int. Необходимо кастовать int в float перед такими операциями.

Comment: Или попросту можно написать

      (a + b) / 2.0

компилятор автоматически приведет сумму к double (поскольку делитель это константа типа double) и результат получится вещественным.

Comment: Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в выражении (целое + целое) = целое, целое / целое = целое. Всегда отсекается дробная часть. Затем мы уже этот результат (целое число) присваиваем дробной переменной.

Как уже правильно отметили, при взаимодействии целого и вещественного, результат будет вещественным.